# How to find all machines with a username via command prompt

Tags: networking, command-line, active-directory

I know my user credentials, they are `User:Johannes`, `Passwort:Pass12345`.
I can find the groups that I am part of with `net`.

```
net user /domain Johannes
```

This gives me the groups I am in.

```
*BELIEVER51
*SOUTHHAMPTONBASKETBALL
*NEVERSAYDIE
```

I Know that the `BELIEVER51` group has access to `ARE42`.
I can connect to `ARE42` via Remote Desktop Protocol using my batch file.

```
cmdkey /generic:"ARE42" /user:"Johannes" /pass:"Pass12345"
start mstsc /v:ARE42
```

All I have is a windows command prompt.
How can I discover all the servers that I can connect to?

Comment: `net view` will list all the local machines that your machines can see. You can RDP into any of them assuming you have access rights.

Comment: ´net view´ does not list ´AREA42´, is there a way to get a list af all of them, especially those that are not local?

Comment: `net view` will only show those that have network discovery on. On another note, talk to your IT department. Just because you *can* remote into a computer doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use powershell, you can run this script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -filter {OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"} -Properties OperatingSystem
$MyServers = @()

$User = "Johannes"
$Password = "Pass12345"

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $User,($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
foreach($Server in $Servers) {
   if( New-PSSession $Server.Name -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Ignore ) {
      $MyServers += $Server.Name
    }
}
```

It'll try to create a session in each server in the domain using the credentials provided. If you can connect to it, it'll success and add the server name to $MyServers. You can then export the variable to a list like this:

```
$MyServers | Out-File "c:\Temp\MyServers.txt"
```